# How to require additional modules in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, tablesort

Hei, I'm trying to get a tablesorter for my app. I wanted to go with this one (https://github.com/tristen/tablesort) but I have problems with getting it to work. I have it in my package.json file and I install it throughout NPM and later require it in code like `var tablesort = require('tablesort');`. The main problem is with modules that come with it. In github project they are required like this: `<script src='tablesort.number.js'></script>`. How can I transform that kind of code to node/require friendly code which will load all those modules and let me sort my tables? I have no idea how to get this tablesorter running with nodejs app.

Comment: Are you using a build tool such as Browserify or Webpack to bundle your app, or are you trying to load in the file directly from your `node_modules`?

Comment: I'm using browserify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [you use Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873368/how-to-require-additional-modules-in-node-js-app?noredirect=1#comment55545884_33873368), you should be allright.

The TableSort library has a CommonJS compatible [export](https://github.com/tristen/tablesort/blob/gh-pages/src/tablesort.js#L243-L244) in its source code. Adding

```
var TableSort = require("tablesort");
```

to your source code should be sufficient to include the library into your built bundle, as well as provide you a reference to the TableSort constructor. The project's README even [has that example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tablesort#node-browserify).

However, the same is not true for the bundled sort-methods, as they expect to find a global reference to the `TableSort` prototype, which they then extend using its extend method, e.g. [TableSort.date](https://github.com/tristen/tablesort/blob/gh-pages/src/sorts/tablesort.date.js#L11-L22).

You can [Browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) to make CommonJS incompatible modules CommonJS compatible. However, in my quick experiments, I couldn't get it working properly without some slicing and dicing. For some reason browserify-shim's file resolution failed when including a file in a subfolder of a package.

I did manage to include the sort-methods by copying them into my project folder.  I made a [Gist demo](https://gist.github.com/nikcorg/6ad48cc1c3d84d98d384) of including one shimmed sort-method. Clone it, run `npm install && npm run build`, then open `index.html` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `tablesort.js` from [here](https://github.com/tristen/tablesort/tree/gh-pages/src)  to your directory, and then
add this to the file:

```
  module.exports =  Tablesort;
```

Then, if you want a spesific tablesort, for example "number". you should download `tablesort.number.js` from [here](https://github.com/tristen/tablesort/tree/gh-pages/src/sorts)

Then, you should add this changes to `tablesort.number.js`

```
    var Tablesort= require('./tablesort.js')

    module.exports =  Tablesort;
```

Finaly, in your file you use this:

```
var tablesort = require('./tablesort.number.js')
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work like this. It says that Tablesort is not defined (inside number module for example if I require number module).

Comment: I get to the point where I have my table rendered but sorting still doesn't work. Although no errors, just table headers are not clickable. And it is a basic html table, nothing special. Should I include some html like classes into the table headers? I saw in example that sort-header class is used but not mentioned anywhere and also sort class in the main table.